# Another way to run class in a subprocess

Tags: java

Currently I have runnable JAR file with package `mypackage` containing main class `Main.class` and one other class `Other.class`.

The point is I am trying to run `Other.class` in subprocess of process which runs the whole JAR.

Now I have something like this in my `Main.class`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp " + Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + " mypackage.Other");
}
```

This works, but I have one problem. I have one more program, which runs the JAR file and then immediatelly deletes it from HDD (because of security reasons). So the `-cp` arguments content can't be valid when the source JAR file doesn't exist.

So I am looking for some way to achieve the same thing, but without the JAR file.

**Idea:** Maybe just run the compiled `Other.class` from RAM or wherever is the JAR content running after its deletion from HDD...

Is there any way?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you are on *completely* wrong way. Your question is a typical example of AB problem. You have problem A and you *think* that you know its solution. There is only one little problem you have now: problem B. Try to explain problem A. Probably you will get much better advise.

Answer (score 0):

you could load the .jar to ram in raw binary, then delete it.  when you need to run it again, save it to the HDD & run.

why do you want to do this? writing a virus?